# How to simulate android sensor events?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing

It's possible to simulate, for instance, events for android accelerometer?

Imagine the following scenario:
I have an app that at some point, if detect a X value from accelerometer, show a dialog with a question to the UI.

I want to make a test for it. To do so, I want to simulate a shake with that X value programatically, and check if the dialog appears.

I already know [Sensor Simulator](https://github.com/openintents/sensorsimulator), but there is a way to send a value for accelerometer or other sensor and receive that changes with SensorEventListener?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. Because sensor event is triggered by hardware, android system get the data from hardware and don't provide interface to change the data or to trigger an sensor event. So we can't simulate a sensor event programatically. Using Sensor Simulator, or you can change the source code of android framework.